# What do Buddhists believe in?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, academic-buddhism

Does Buddhism say everything is an illusion? For Buddhist, are all other people just an illusion (philosophical zombies)? For example, when I talk to a Buddhist, he thinks I'm a philosophical zombie without minds,feeling,emotions? It turns out that all people in the world believe that other people have consciousness besides the Buddhism?I don't think this is true, so I want to clarify thanks

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism teaches what is commonly called the human life form is comprised of five aggregates ([SN 22.48](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.48/en/bodhi); [SN 22.22](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.22/en/bodhi)), namely, body, feelings (of pleasantness, unpleasantness & in-between), perceptions, mental formations (such as emotions & thinking) and consciousness via the six senses.

Buddhism teaches what is commonly called "the self" is merely a product of thinking and conditioning ([SN 22.81](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.81/en/bodhi#sc10)) and is not ultimately real and is merely the manifesting of suffering ([SN 5.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn05/sn05.010.bodh.html)). Therefore, Buddhism teaches the five aggregates are "not-self" ("anatta"; [SN 22.59](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html)).

Buddhism says anatta (not-self) is only the true nature of things but is also the understanding that leads to the ending of suffering because, according to the 1st Noble Truth ([SN 56.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.11/en/bodhi#sc4)) all suffering is caused by the mind possessively clinging/attaching to things (the five aggregates; SN 56.11), both internally & externally, as "I", "me", "mine" and "self" ([SN 22.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.001.than.html)).

The sole purpose of the Buddhist teachings is to mitigate and end suffering ([MN 22 paragraph 56](https://suttacentral.net/mn22/en/bodhi#sc56)). Here, it is taught nothing whatsoever should be attached to (as "I" & "mine"; [MN 37](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books9/Bhikkhu_Bodhi_Culatanhasankhaya_Sutta.htm)).

In Hinduism, when it is taught "everything is an illusion", the purpose of this teaching is also to end suffering and made the mind feel more free & unattached.

In summary, Buddhism believes if you can live according to the [Noble Eightfold Path](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.8/en/bodhi) you can live a life that is free from suffering.